# Single table Inheritance name collisions

Tags: sql, database-design

I've been using STI for a table called Journey. People will post journey requests/offers, so the Discriminator will be either: Driver or Passenger, meaning there will be journeys posted by someone who is willing to drive and take other passengers, or people who are just hitchhiking (passenger). So these two would share most of the attributes (such as the date of departure, source, destination etc.), but there will be some name collisions due to the type of the user who is posting.

For instance, if I am a passenger I may specify that I want to travel with my friend (thus having a PassengerCount = 2, i.e. we look for drivers who have at least 2 available seats). Or I may note that, I want to bring some luggage with me (thus having HaveLuggage = true, i.e. I'm looking for rides who can take my luggage)

On the other hand, if I am a driver, I should fill a form where I can specify the number of available seats (AvailableSeats) and I may note that I can't transport luggage (TakesLuggage=false).

As you can see the columns PassengerCount - AvailableSeats and HaveLuggage - TakesLuggage are the same, only their name differs from the posters perspective.

So the question is, what naming convention should I follow in order to minimize confusion? Also, is this a good idea to have one table like this (STI), if not, what alternative would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you need to worry so much about naming conventions...  You've already got the distinguishing property (type).  Labels can be added on data-out that would distinguish however you liked.  Example:

```
Journey
   Type (integer) -- 1 = provider, 2 = consumer
   Passengers (integer)
   Luggage (bit / bool) -- 1 = yes, 0 = no
```

so as for naming convention:

```
SELECT "Driver", passengers as "Avaliable Seats", luggage as "Takes Luggage" WHERE type=1
UNION
SELECT "Passenger", passengers as "Passenger Count", luggage as "Have Luggage" WHERE type=2
```

Or you could use control statements (IF/CASE/etc) in the SELECT itself.